# How to remove item in List?

Tags: list, classcastexception, concurrentmodification, copyonwritearraylist

I have two List in nest for loop, When I matched a item in inner, I want to remove it so that performance will up.

```
List<String[]> brandList = readCsvFile("/tmp/brand.csv");
List<String[]> themeList = readCsvFile("/tmp/theme.csv");

for (String[] brand : brandList) {
    for (String[] theme : themeList) {
        if (brand[0].equals(theme[0])) {
            themeList.remove(theme);
        }
    }
}
```

I got a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` error. If I changed to CopyOnWriteArrayList, The error as below:

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<String[]> themeList = (CopyOnWriteArrayList<String[]>)readCsvFile("/tmp/theme.csv");

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList
```

Now how can I do? omit remove? or anyway else?

I think this is what I need:

```
List<String[]> brandList = readCsvFile("/tmp/brand.csv");
List<String[]> themeList = readCsvFile("/tmp/theme.csv");

for (String[] brand : brandList) {
    List<String[]> toRemove = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    for (String[] theme : themeList) {
        if (brand[0].equals(theme[0])) {
            toRemove.add(theme);
        }
    }

    for (String[] theme : toRemove) {
        themeList.removeAll(theme);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't remove items from a `Collection` while you are iterating over it, which it was a `foreach` loop in Java essentially does. You have to create a new `List<String[]>` and collect all elements you wish to remove, then delete them in bulk after you have iterated through the `Collection`:

```
List<String[]> brandList = readCsvFile("/tmp/brand.csv");
List<String[]> themeList = readCsvFile("/tmp/theme.csv");
List<String[]> toRemove = new ArrayList<String[]>();

for (String[] brand : brandList) {
    for (String[] theme : themeList) {
        if (brand[0].equals(theme[0])) {
            toRemove.add(theme);
        }
    }
}
themeList.removeAll(theme);
```

Comment: Your code is not what I want, can I put themeList.removeAll(toRemove); inside outer loop?

Comment: It is more efficient to put this outside the loops, as only one delete operation is performed for all elements to be removed. It is of course possible, but from this code fragment I don't see where the semantic difference lies.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as pretty, but you can do it using iterators:

```
List<String[]> brandList = readCsvFile("/tmp/brand.csv");
List<String[]> themeList = readCsvFile("/tmp/theme.csv");

for (String[] brand : brandList) {
    Iterator<String[]> themeIterator = themeList.iterator();
    while (themeIterator.hasNext()) {
        String[] theme = themeIterator.next();
        if (brand[0].equals(theme[0])) {
            themeIterator.remove();
            // If you are sure there is only one theme per brand, add a break here
            // break;
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the concrete type of `List<>` `themeList` is (array list, linked list etc), this may or may not be faster than the copy variant.

Comment: One brand has multiple themes!

Comment: Which is why the break is commented out :)

Comment: This code will produce a `ConcurrentModificationException` as well. Also, a `foreach` loop is nothing but an `Iterator` internally.

Comment: The point of using the iterator is that the `iterator.remove()` method allows for item removal during iteration (in contrast to `collection.remove(x)`). With certain limitations, such as there must be exactly one iterator operating on the list when `remove()` is called. See the documentation for the concrete collection used for details. As you know, although it uses an iterator, the `foreach` syntax does not expose this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 features, something like this might serve, and might be faster:

```
List<String[]> brandList = readCsvFile("/tmp/brand.csv");
List<String[]> themeList = readCsvFile("/tmp/theme.csv");

// Extract unique values of the first column from the brand list
// into a structure suited for fast lookup
Set<String> names = brandList.stream()
        .map(columns -> columns[0])
        .collect(Collectors.toSet())

// Remove all entries from themeList where the value of the
// first column exists in names
themeList.removeIf(columns -> names.contains(columns[0]))
```